# Integration Upper Sum

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I have been given a real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}}$$
and i have to argue that the sequence is an upper sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \ dx$$
I am not sure how to do this though. I have looked at the definition for upper sums given by:
$$
U(D)=\sum_{i=1}^n G_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
where
$$
G_i=\sup \{f(x) \ | \ x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\}$$
However, i cannot see how this is supposed to help me here..

Comment: This follows immediately from considering the partition $x_j=\frac{j}{n}$. What is the supremum of $\sqrt{x}$ in the interval $(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n})$?

Comment: Could supremum be 1 in that interval? Or am i understanding this wrong

Comment: Say $n=3$. The intervals are $[0,1/3),[2/3,1/3), (1/3,1]$. Can you calculate the supremum of $\sqrt{x}$ in each of these intervals?

Comment: Would supremum then be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$, $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ and $\sqrt{1}$? So supremum is $\sqrt{\frac{j}{n}}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is monotone increasing, therefore the upper Riemann sum:
$$
\frac{1-0}{n}\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{0+1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{0+2}{n}} + \ldots + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \bigg)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}
$$
is the upper bound on the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}dx
$$

Comment: Calculations make sense to me, however, i cannot see how you have shown that it is an upper sum for my integral... Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Pls see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You could work the summation using generalized harmonic numbers
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{j}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Using asymptotics
$$H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2 n^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{n^{1/2}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.