# Limit of sequence of series $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{j}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given the series (sequence of series, really) $$a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}}$$
 what is its limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$? (I happen to know its 2/3, but how does one show it?)

(Note I've seen a few solutions using something called 'Generalized Harmonics' - these, however, **do not** figure in any of my text books, so I'd like to avoid using them, if possible)

P.s. I realize [another recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690617/integration-upper-sum) deals with the same sequence (I take it the questioner goes to the same university as I). But that post was with regards to showing $a_n$ to be an upper sum of $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}$, which is an issue of partitions and suprema. I felt my question was sufficiently different that I did not want to relegate it to a comment in the other thread.

Comment: You want to show that this Riemann sum's limit is $2/3$ without using its Riemann summiness?

Comment: When did I say I didn't want to use its "Riemann summiness"? - I'm not trying to be zany, I am genuniely asking. I do not know what "Generalized Harmonics" are; they aren't mentioned in my text books.

Comment: You didn't say it, but it seems implicit in your claim that it's a different question from the one you linked to.  I'd say the answers there are the most straightforward ways to show the limit.

Comment: Incidentally, sorry my first comment sounded flippant.  I wasn't intending to demean your question; I just get a kick out of using words like "summiness."

Comment: That's alright :) - But yes the other question did seem to answer how to find the limit (the second answer, specifically) but it used the "Generalized Harmonics" approach, which I'm trying to avoid. I also didn't know exactly how to get the limit of the function, from having proven it to be the upper sum of the integral --- but that has, of course, been explained in this thread. So it's all good now.

Comment: One of the solutions used that, the other alluded to the Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **norm** of a partition $P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsc < x_n = b \}$ of an interval $[a, b]$ is defined as $\Vert P \Vert = \max \{x_i - x_{i-1} : i = 1, \dotsc, n \}.$

Given a bounded function $f \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and a partition $P = \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsc < x_n = b \}$ of $[a, b],$ for each choice of values $s_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i],$ the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(s_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})$$
is said to be a **Riemann sum** of $f$ associated to $P.$

One can prove that if $f$ is Riemann-integrable in $[a, b]$ and $(P_n)$ is a sequence of partitions of $[a, b]$ with $\Vert P_n \Vert \to 0$ as $n \to \infty,$ then for any sequence $(\mathcal{S}_n)$ of Riemann sums of $f$ with $\mathcal{S}_n$ associated to $P_n$ for each $n,$ it holds that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{S}_n = \int_a^b f.$$

In your case, just apply this result to the function $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ (which is continuous, hence Riemann integrable), the sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ with
$$P_n = \left\{ \frac{i}{n} : i = 0, \dotsc, n \right\} = \left\{ 0 < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{2}{n} < \dotsb < 1 \right\}$$
(which satisfies $\Vert P_n \Vert = 1/n \to 0$) and the choice of values $s_i = i/n \in [(i-1)/n, i/n]$ for each $n.$

Answer (score 2):

This is the Riemann sum for
$\int_0^1 x^{1/2}dx
=\dfrac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}\big|_0^1
=\dfrac23
$.

(added later)

To be more rigorous,
if $f(x)$ is increasing,
$\int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n} f(x) dx
\le \frac1{n}f(j/n)
\le \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f(x) dx  
$.
Summing,
$\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n} f(x) dx
\le \sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{n}f(j/n)
\le \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f(x) dx  
$
or
$\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx
\le \frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f(j/n)
\le \int_{1/n}^{1+1/n} f(x) dx  
$.

Therefore,
if $\lim_{n \to \infty}(|\int_0^{1/n}f(x)dx|+|\int_1^{1+1/n}f(x)dx|)
=0$,
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f(j/n)
= \int_{0}^1 f(x) dx
$.
This will hold if
$f$ is bounded.
Weaker conditions will also work,
but this is enough here.

The reverse inequality
(with the same limit) holds
if $f$ is decreasing.

If $f(x) = x^a$ where $a > 0$,
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (j/n)^a
= \int_{0}^1 x^a dx
=\dfrac{1}{a+1}
$.

Comment: Okay, but how does one show the sequence/series is equal to the integral? You show it's an oversum because, for some partitiion $x_j = j/n$ the oversum is $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} sup\{f(x) | x\in \bigg[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\bigg]\} \bigg(\frac{j}{n}-\frac{j-1}{n}\bigg) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}} (1/n) = a_n$$

Then you find its lower sum similarly $$L = \sum_{j=1}^{n}  \sqrt{\frac{j-1}{n}} (1/n)$$... and what's next?

Comment: @Woodenplank: Then squeeze.  Recognize that $L = H - \frac1n$, and this difference goes to $0$.

Comment: What is H in this example? --- I have solved the issue by now, and indeed used the squeezing lemma. Although I did $$L \leq \underline{\int_a^b} f(x) dx \leq \overline{\int_a^b} f(x) dx \leq U$$ where U is the upper bound; $a_n$ in this case.

Comment: @Woodenplank: Haha, I just used $H$ for "high" rather than $U$ for "upper," that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Without Riemann:
$$
\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt{k}
$$
This sum can be upper-bounded by the corresponding integral with support $[0, n+1]$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{k} < \int_{0}^{n+1}\sqrt{x}dx = \frac{2 (n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}
$$
Since 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 1
$$
The upper bound on the sum is $\frac{2}{3}$. Now do the same with the lower bound:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{k} > \int_{0}^{n-1}\sqrt{x}dx
$$
Which is also $\frac{2}{3}$ as $n \to \infty$.